# How to make the new popup window appear in front of the current window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed VSCodium 1.69.1 on Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon.
When I click the
*File, Open File*
or any other menu,
The new popup window will
appear behind the current window.
How to make the new popup window appear in front of the current window?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is identified and a fix is being pursued on the upstream VS Code repository: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146422